# Android databinding "enabled" in build.gradle is deprecated

Tags: android, gradle, data-binding

in `build.gradle` file:

```
dataBinding {
     enabled = true
 }
```

`enabled` is deprecated. Can't find any documentation about it.
Anyone has any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try replacing it with

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
```

Comment: Not working for me. I see the next message: No candidates found for method call dataBinding.

Comment: @Patrick are you sure you're using buildFeatures {} inside android {} ?

Comment: @Patrick what's your Gradle plugin version?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30"

Comment: Try deleting the .gradle folder, and also "Invalidate Caches and Restart" in the Android Studio

Comment: worked for me. Android Studio Giraffee 2022.3.1 Patch 1

Answer (score 1):

New android studio versions require

```
 buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true //for viewbinding
    dataBinding = true //for dataBinding
}
```