# Enabling dataBinding in build.grade - no candtidates found for method called

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to enable data binding in my android studio application.
To do this, I add enable it in my build.grade file

[image: Enabling databinding lines 23-25]

However, when I hover over dataBinding, a warning pops up that says "No candidates found for method call dataBinding."

[image: No candidates found for method call dataBinding.]

And I cannot use databinding in my project. It appears to be an issue with build.gradle but from what I understand this should be automatically generated by android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62444749/12099357)?

Try removing below

```
dataBinding { 
   enabled true
}
```